# Register internal dependency using Autofac in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, given we have an `interface IUserRepository` and a concrete implementation `class UserRepository : IUserRepository`, registered as such using Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>()
       .As<IUserRepository>();
```

And controllers registered as such:

```
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

If we had a controller such as:

```
public class JumpController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            // `this.User` is `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`
            return AppUser.Find(this.User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // Sweet!
        this.CurrentUser.Jump();

        return this.RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
}
```

Where  `AppUser` is a domain object such as:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }

    public void Jump()
    {
        this.UserRepository.Jump(this);
    }

    public static AppUser Find(string userName)
    {
        return this.UserRepository.Find(userName);
    }

    // we don't want consumers of the `AppUser` type know about our private matters ...
    private IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            // ... and we *wish* `AppUser` didn't "know" about Autofac either! ;-(
            return AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

How could we register `class UserRepository : IUserRepository` in a better way so that `AppUser` doesn't "know" about `AutofacDependencyResolver`, possibly without compromising desired dependency hiding?

Comment: Part of the benefit of inversion of control is to assist in testing, in much the same way TDD impacts design and testability. By trying so hard to hide the `IUserRepository` from everything - including constructor injection - you're really treading into design anti-pattern territory. If it's really hard to do what you're trying to do... sometimes that's a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Constructor Dependency Injection` when you want to resolve a specific type.

1. Controller is using injection `JumpController(AppUser appUser)`.
2. AppUser class is using injection for repository.

**Example:** (Not been tested)

```
public class JumpController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    private AppUser _appUser { get; set; }

    public JumpController(AppUser appUser)
    {
        _appUser = appUser;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        _appUser.Jump(username);
        return this.RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    // Rest of the code
}

public class AppUser
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository { get; set; }

    public AppUser(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Jump(string username)
    {
        _userRepository.Jump(this);
    }

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: This way you exposed `IUserRepository` to `AppUser`'s public interface (which is precisely what I would like to avoid and instead "configure" via Autofac, rather than exposing it publicly).

Also, I don't follow you when you proposed passing `username` as parameter to `AppUser#Jump`. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe a delegate factory or property injection would be better? Not sure, nor do I seem to able to get my head around those.